# How do I disable "Run Monitor" in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I'm using NetBeans IDE v7.0.1.
When I try to run a program (F6 Shortcut), There is a pop-up window in the left side named "Run Monitor". How do I disable it?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

go into your project properties (right-click on the project --> properties or go to the "File" menu and select your project properties), select "profile" and uncheck the box "Show profiling indicators during run"

Answer (score 5):

In more recent versions of NetBeans, we can disable HTTP monitor
in the Server Properties dialog. In the Services tab, we expand
the Server node. We right click on Apache Tomcat and select Properties.
In the Connection tab we uncheck the Enable HTTP monitor option.
We also may need to restart Tomcat.

[image]